# How to randomize an array of objects in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object, random, shuffle

I have this example of an array of objects and I need to randomize it each time I do a `foreach` loop.

Looks like `shuffle` works only on arrays.

One thing is that I cant convert this into an array, because then it will become a `STD object` which I can't use, because of the way my mapper works.

```
array(48) {
  [0] => object(Friends_Model_Friends)#142 (4) {
    ["_id":protected] => NULL
    ["_tal":protected] => object(stdClass)#194 (3) {
      ["thumb"] => object(stdClass)#196 (6) {
        ["id"] => string(8) "10884697"
        ["type"] => string(1) "2"
        ["gallery"] => string(1) "1"
      }
    }
    ["_friend":protected] => string(7) "3492149"
    ["_dependent_table":protected] => NULL
  }
  [1] => object(Friends_Model_Friends)#195 (4) {
    ["_id":protected] => NULL
    ["_tal":protected] => object(stdClass)#143 (3) {
      ["thumb"] => object(stdClass)#202 (6) {
        ["id"] => string(8) "11160632"
        ["type"] => string(1) "2"
        ["gallery"] => string(1) "1"
      }
    }
    ["_friend":protected] => string(7) "3301541"
    ["_dependent_table":protected] => NULL
  }
....
```

Any ideas on shuffling this?

**edit:** `Zend_Debug::dump(shuffle($object));` returns `bool(true)`

Comment: You are telling, that you have an array, but then you say, that `shuffle` only works with arrays and you can't convert it [the array]  into an array, because it will become an object? Sorry, but that makes completely no sense to me...

Comment: So, did you try `shuffle()` and it didn't shuffle the array?

Comment: @Patrioticcow What result do you get from the `shuffle()` call? In what way does it not work? Can you show the code you used to call it?

Comment: if i do `Zend_Debug::dump(shuffle($object));` i get `bool(true)`

Comment: damn, im stupid. hold on

Comment: @Patrioticcow [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) shuffles the array, but _returns_ a boolean.

Comment: youre right, im just fu**ing stupid today. It works just fine

Comment: @Patrioticcow Like many of the functions that are native to PHP that are designed around indexed arrays, `shuffle()` assumes you are working with a stack-like structure and takes the input data by reference, modifying the original store and not returning a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the objects are in an array, not another object so you can use `shuffle`...

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$my_array;
echo '<pre>'; print_r($my_array); echo '</pre>';
shuffle ($my_array);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($my_array); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Try this code

Answer (score 3):

Shuffle always returns a boolean:

```
bool shuffle ( array &$array )
```

So you can't return it like

```
return shuffle( $myAwesomeArray );
```

This is what I just did and I wondered why it didn't give anything back, as you're probably expecting your shuffled array back.

You just have to call it like this

```
shuffle( $myAwesomeArray );
return $myAwesomeArray;
```

And all should work just fine.